# Hide Login form upon sucessful submit PHP

Tags: php, html

Im building a login page and I want to hide my login form upon successful submission. I have all the required code to tell me if the submit is successful I just can't get the form to find once it is successful. does anyone know how I would hide the form at the same time as displaying the successful login message.

login_page.php -

```
        <?php
    require('includes/application_top.php');
    $page_title='Login!';
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $username_input = $_POST['username'];
        $password_input = $_POST['password'];
        $login_ok = login($username_input, $password_input);
    }
    require('includes/site_header.php');
    ?>
    <style>
    <?php
    require('css/login.css');
    ?>
    </style>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php
            if (isset($login_ok)) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $login_ok) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <p>Your credentials were invalid</p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <p>Login successful</p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
      <div id="formContent">
        <!-- Icon -->
        <div class="fadeIn first">
          <br>
          <img src="images/Head1.jpg" style="height: 40%; width: 60%;" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
          <br>
          <h3> Login! </h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!-- Login Form -->
        <form id="login_form" action="login_page.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" class="fadeIn second" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?= isset($_POST['username']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : '' ?>" maxlength="100" />
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" />
          <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" name="action" value="Login"/>
        </form>

        <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
        <div id="formFooter">
          <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    require('includes/application_bottom.php');
    require('includes/site_footer.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: Or you can put the whole login form in a variable and if `$login_ok` is not set using`if(!isset($login_ok))` echo it out and elseif its set but `$login_ok` is not true echo out the form together with the error and else echo out the alert-success without the form. not the most efficient way though I would say

Comment: Okay how owuld i add that to my code?